# concourse setting container timezone

Tags: docker, containers, concourse

In my concourse docker container  I want the timezone to be a particular timezone (let's say america/montreal).

Is there a way to declare container timezone in my pipeline's yaml ?

Answer (score 2):

For timezone to be set in a container 2 conditions must be met:

- the image used by the concourse task must be timezone-aware, i.e. in case of Ubuntu images it must have `tzdata` package installed
- The `TZ` env variable has to be set, e.g. `TZ=America/Montreal`

This is a docker file for a sample TZ-aware image:

```
# oozie/montreal
FROM ubuntu
ENV TZ=America/Montreal
RUN apt update && apt install -y tzdata
```

The following pipeline with a task embedded in it results in a timezoned output, which can be overriden with a TZ variable for individual commands:

```
jobs:
  - name: timezoned-task
    plan:
    - task: tz-aware
      config:
        platform: linux
        image_resource:
          type: docker-image
          source:
            repository: oozie/montreal
        run:
          path: /bin/bash
          args:
          - -c
          - |
            date
            TZ=UTC date
```

[image: timezoned task]